# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo(tensorflow.lite.examples)

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am working on this project: TensorFlow Lite image classification Android example application

GitHub link: https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android

I run this project on my own phone (xiaomi redmi note 8) on Android Studio (not emulator)

When I run this project on Android Studio, TFL Classify applications gives the following error: application keep stopping.

Then Android Studio gives this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification, PID: 20798
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.ClassifierActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.tflite.Classifier.Model.QUANTİZED_EFFİCİENTNET
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1839)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6864)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.tflite.Classifier.Model.QUANTİZED_EFFİCİENTNET
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:258)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.tflite.Classifier$Model.valueOf(Classifier.java:47)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:195)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7232)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7221)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2964)
```

I updated SDK version 28 to 29.0.2 but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the accents from the string `QUANTİZED_EFFİCİENTNET` - it should be `QUANTIZED_EFFICIENTNET` so it matches the corresponding enum label.

Comment: I looked inside required code but there is QUANTIZED_EFFICIENTNET ,not QUANTİZED_EFFİCİENTNET .I didnt understand this error.Project works fine on emulator

Comment: Yes you are right.I looked app->res->values->strings.xml part 

'''
<item>Quantized_Efficientnet</item>
<item>Float_Efficientnet</item>
<item>Quantized_MobileNet</item>
 <item>Float_Mobilenet</item>
'''
Then i changed like this

'''
<item>QUANTIZED_EFFICIENTNET</item>
        <item>FLOAT_EFFICIENTNET</item>
        <item>QUANTIZED_MOBILENET</item>
        <item>FLOAT_MOBILENET</item>
'''
Problem is solved
Thanks for your solution